# Is there any way to configure .htaccess to write to access.log file which is already handled by apache2.config

Tags: .htaccess

We have hosted our website with external agency, in the Linux environment.
now we have added cookies in our website code and want to track cookie in access.log. when we requested with our domain host provider they turn down the request to modify apache2.config file, instead they suggested to use .htaccess file to enable cookie in access.log. Right now we do not want to use any other method to log cookie other than .htaccess file.

we did not find any solutions to enable cookie in access.log using .htaccess file.

we need following questions to be answered.

1) Is it possible to use .htaccess file to enable cookie in access.log

2) If yes, steps to make it and it will be greatly appreciated if it is explained keeping it in mind that user is a layman.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot customize log files from .htaccess. And I think there is a valid reason of disabling this as it may impose security issues in a shared environment.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the host enable [mod_usertrack](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_usertrack.html). Then they would need to allow you to override the configuration settings with `.htaccess`.

```
LogFormat "%{Apache}n %r %t" usertrack
CustomLog logs/clickstream.log usertrack
```

I track cookies, users, sessions, browsers, everything in a MySQL database. It's a lot easier to access the data with stats than log mining. (It does take up a bit of room though.)